# Программный поиск и замена в MS Word с помощью Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#

Есть код

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Word.Application objWord = new Word.Application();
  objWord.Visible = true;
  Word.Document doc = objWord.Documents.Open("test.docx");
  object findText = "A";
  object replaceWithText = "B";
  object matchCase = false;
  object matchWholeWord = true;
  object matchWildCards = false;
  object matchSoundsLike = false;
  object matchAllWordForms = false;
  object forward = true;
  object format = false;
  object matchKashida = false;
  object matchDiacritics = false;
  object matchAlefHamza = false;
  object matchControl = false;
  object read_only = false;
  object visible = true;
  object replace = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
  object wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
  doc.Activate();
  objWord.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                                 ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike,
                                 ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, 
                                 ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, 
                                 ref replace, ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, 
                                 ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
}
```

Этот код заменяет все буквы "A" на "B", но почему-то игнорирует колонтитулы (возможно и ещё что-то) как это исправить? Мне необходимо поменять символ A на B во всем документе (текст, колонтитулы, таблицы, содержимое фигур и т.д.)

P.S. необходимо заменить именно символ, о строке речь не идёт. Возможно есть более "шустрые методы"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeadersFooters` 
Это свойство есть у `section.Headers` и `section.Footers` 
которые берутся если разбить документ `Word.Document doc`
на секции, к примеру с помощью

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in doc.Sections)
```

Comment: Спасибо, также добавил `foreach (Word.Range range in doc.StoryRanges) foreach (Word.Shape shape in range.ShapeRange)`